# How to fix this routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this route

```
resources :boards do
   member do
      get :move
      post :move_category
      get :notify
      post :notify_create
      delete :notify_destroy
   end
   resources :topics
  end
```

The problem is with `:notify_destroy` The route reports as

```
notify_destroy_board DELETE /boards/:id/notify_destroy(.:format) {:action=>"notify_destroy", :controller=>"boards"}


link_to "Remove Notification",notify_destroy_board_path(board),:method=>:delete, :confirm=>true
```

results in this error: `No route matches "/boards/2/notify_destroy"` which seems to be the exact route that rake routes report.

I am sure I am missing something simple but I can't see where it is. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Zabba,the issue is solved. It was including MochiKit JS library into my app that was causing the Javascript issue.

Interestingly, if I put the links to the MochiKit file above the <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> tag, the problem also disappears. I guess I need to read up more on why this is.

Comment: What is the URL returned by `notify_destroy_board_path(board)` ? And are you using Rails 3.0.x or 3.1.x ? And in your routes file, make sure you have not repeated the `resources` somewhere else in the file, thus overwriting the routes you are looking at.

Comment: 3.0.9 and `<a href="/boards/2/notify_destroy" data-confirm="true" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Remove Notification</a>`

Comment: Is JavaScript enabled in your browser? Is the `rails.js` file being referenced in the HTML source of the page the link is in (e.g. `<%= javascript_include_tag "rails" %>`)? Most likely, in the log, just above the error `No route matches`, the HTTP method is probably showing a `GET` instead of a `POST` or `PUT` ?

Comment: JS is being referenced and you are right, the log shows it as a GET. Which makes no sense because I have another link on a different page that points to a DELETE method and is setup the exact same way, only difference is the path.

Comment: To give you an example of the similar link `link_to "Delete?",destroy_topic_post_path(post.topic,post),:method=>:delete, :confirm=>true` this works just fine.

Comment: Are you using `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in both pages where the links are (current problem link's page and the working link)?

Comment: I figured it out. I placed the delete link_to that works in the page with the link_to I am having the issue and the same no route error pops up on it. The problem is that this page with the issue, also links to mochi kit for table sorting. Removing that solves the issue, but why would mochi kit get in the way?

Comment: Thank you for talking me through it. I appreciate it. I guess I should ask a different question about mochikit or just figure out how to do it with Prototype.